# Connect Java spring project with cloud database

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, spring-cloud-gcp

I have created a spring boot project in Java, it works perfectly fine with my local database but I am not able to connect it to my GCP postgres cloud SQL instance.

I have followed the below steps: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/multi/multi__spring_jdbc.html
I also did the required changes in the pom.xml.
Is there anything I need to change in the application.properties file?

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/schema.sql
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

I want my project to working properly, pointing to cloud database.

Comment: please provide the error you are facing right now. You probably have an exception in the logs with an error message related to the database. It would be easier to figuring out what's wrong if we have that error to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on which cloud you are using.

There is End Point for you created database.

That Endpoint link you have to put instead of Localhost.`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://(put your end point here instead of localhost):5432/postgres`

Make sure that your database name should be same as in the link.

If you are using Spring there so you should first create database development environment.

Other than in Pom.xml you need to add Dependency of cloud.

If you want to access that DB then you have to go for JackDB platform.

Thanks & Regards,

JerryRank

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help me what dependency do I need to add in pom.xml.

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>                                                                                                                                         You need to add this dependency and check plugins also for google if you are using GCP.